# Remotely Play Games on PC While Someone is Using It

Tags: remote-access, streaming, remote-desktop, multi-user

Basically what I would like is for someone to be able to remote onto my PC and stream a video game while I'm still using it.

I've tried Steam In-Home Streaming, but that takes control of the entire computer so only one person can use it, and I've also tried the RDP hack that allows multiple sessions (like windows server) but that compresses the image badly and the streaming quality is abysmal.

I would like a software that allows me to do multi-session RDP but it can stream a game at a nice FPS with nice compression. Does such a software exist, and if so, does it

Comment: What you could do is set up a Virtual Machine (or two) and have the Guest (or one VM) be used by someone, and the Host (or the other VM) be used by someone else. Check [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuJYMCbIbPk) out if you are curious to learn more.

Comment: Exactly. But for maximum performance make sure the VM has a direct access to a discrete GPU. Then the host should use the integrated GPU.

Comment: @MrPublic as user31389 said, I don't have two discrete GPUs, nor do I have integrated graphics, and using some simulated VM GPU won't cut it for gaming. Furthermore, I'm not interested in installing unRAID onto my computer, I would like to keep Windows, if possible.

Comment: What version of Windows are you Running?

Comment: @MrPublic Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, all these years later someone upvoted which reminded me of this question. There is one way to do it that I've found that works.

1. First, use [RDPWrap](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) to enable multiple RDP sessions if you have not already. Create as many Windows user accounts as you need.
2. Keep RDP graphical context alive while minimized [[1]](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0dd103cc-0da3-4d78-9a79-7aaf8598184c/using-remotedesktopsuppresswhenminimized-for-a-nested-rdp-session?forum=winserverTS)

   1. Find the registry keys:

      - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`
      - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`
   2. Create a `DWORD` value with the name `RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized` and set its value to `2`.
3. Install [Parsec](https://parsec.app/), [Rainway](https://rainway.com/), or your preferred remote desktop service. GeForce Experience/Moonlight does not seem to play well, but YMMV.
4. On the host, use the loopback address (`127.0.0.2`) and open an RDP session to each user.
5. In each RDP session, open your remote desktop app and set it up so you can connect.

Congrats! Hopefully you should be able to have multiple games sharing your graphics card at the same time.